# ctx fill Style не работает

Tags: canvas

```
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
if (canvas.getContext) {
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(10,0);
ctx.lineTo(10,150);
ctx.lineTo(0,150);

ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(7,50,0,150);
ctx.strokeStyle="#abc";
ctx.fillStyle="green";
ctx.stroke();}}
</script>~~~
```

Comment: Вы не вызываете fill...

Comment: Эм,а как сделать

Comment: вызвать и stroke и fill

Comment: Можете объяснить поподробнее

Comment: ctx.fillRect так

Comment: Все,понял как надо